# Using superclass instance method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, factory, factory-method, instancetype

I'm confused in using instancetype in Objective-C.

Code:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

-(instancetype)initWithOwner:(NSString*)anOwner;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* owner;
@end


@interface MyChildClass : MyClass

-(instancetype)init;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* myString;
@end
```

Then, I'm able to run this

```
MyChildClass* myChildObject = [[MyChildClass alloc] initWithOwner:@"owner"];
```

Why does this return MyChildClass and not MyClass ???

Why doesn't compiler show any warning or error message, that I'm using the initializer method of a superclass, and not MyChildClass initializer method ???

Where can I use this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Question (Question marks 1 to 3)

This is because of `instancetype`. It says: The return instance is of the same type (or a subclass) as the receiver has.

```
[[MyChildClass alloc] initWithOwner:@"owner"];
```

Means:

```
[[MyChildClass alloc] -> MyChildClass
                                      initWithOwner:@"owner"] -> MyChildClass;
```

2. Question (Question marks 4 to 6)

a. There are no factory methods in Objective-C. There are methods in Objective-C.

b. The compiler shows no warning, because everything is fine. You assign a reference to `MyChildClass` to a reference variable of the type `MyChildClass`.

3. Question (Question marks 7 to 9)

You can use this in your example. `MyChildClass` can use the base' class implementation, if it does not want to change it. (Very often.)

BTW: Do you know that the returned instance is of the type `MyChildClass`?

Comment: I've checked it with NSLog(@"%@", [myChildObject className]); it's MyChildClass. As I understood it will be MyChildClass because of alloc method, which returnes MyChildClass.

Comment: According to your answer, if I don't want to change my superclass instance method, I should use this. But isn't it better to override this method in MyChildClass @implementation ? in that implementation I set self = [super initWithOwner:...]; and then I set my properties to the default value, cause when I call superclass instance method, MyChildClass properties are assigned to NULL, and If I won't check it later, I'll get problems while using this properties. The point is: isn't it better instead of using superclass instance methods to override them ?

Comment: 1. For `+alloc` this does not apply. 2. For `-init…` it depends on the initializer, esp. if it is a designated or secondary initializer. However, calling `-init…` (`super`) would lead to the "problem", that initializers have to be `id` typed, which is worse. Nowadays, for initializers `id` is automatically replaced with `instancetype` for that reason.

Comment: Not sure what point you were trying to make by stating, "There are no factory methods in Objective-C," but that's incorrect.  From Apple's *Concepts in Objective-C Programming*: "Class factory methods are implemented by a class as a convenience for clients. They combine allocation and initialization in one step and return the created object."

Comment: This is a convention that has nothing to do with Objective-C. In contrast to other programming languages, Objective-C does not have a language level concept of object creation. So there is nothing special with them and `instancetype` apply exactly the same way to all other methods. (ARC makes some assumptions via the method name, but this is for legacy related to MRR.) So the citation is related to a convention, but not to a language concept.